# Increment tuples in a map

Tags: c++, memory, data-structures, tuples, maps

I have the following member of a class I am using:

```
std::map<std::string, std::tuple<double, double, int>> errors;
```

The idea is we loop over a series of bins each with a std::string name, and 3 values associated with it.

We would like to add each bank to the map when the error is over a certain threshold and sum the three values.

I currently have:

```
 std::map<std::string, std::tuple<double, double, int>> errors;

std::string binname = "BIN1";
double mean = 5.5;
double stddev = 12.3;
int count = 1;

errors.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(binname),
std::forward_as_tuple(mean, stddev, count));
```

Which works fine to add new banks to the list. But I need something to sum the tuples when the banks are already have an entry from that bank. Ie something like:

```
if(errors.find(binname))
{
    errors.find(binname).first += mean;
    errors.find(binname).second += stddev;
    errors.find(binname).third += 1;
}
```

Or something similar. I guess I could pull the tuple add each element individually and create a new entry. Is that the best approach? I am not 100% set to the structure itself but would be nice to keep it as such.

Comment: Creating dedicated struct with named fields might be clearer than tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17, with [Structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), you might unconditionally do:

```
auto& [err_mean, err_stddev, err_count] = errors[binname];
err_mean += mean;
err_stddev += stddev;
err_count += 1;
```

`errors[binname]` will create default entry (`{0., 0., 0}`) if not present.

For pre-c++17,

```
auto& tup = errors[binname];
std::get<0>(tup) += mean;
std::get<1>(tup) += stddev;
std::get<2>(tup) += 1;
```

Comment: Wow this is cool stuff.

I believe we are pre 17 unfortunately but that second solution looks good anyway.

But also if you're saying errors[binname] will auto initialise it for me as 0,0,0 then add mean, stddev, and count I actually only need that section in my code right? If it doesn't exist it will just auto initiate and add my values?

Comment: You need only one look-up. No need to do `find` before.